# Get the total sum of all the rows in table using jquery

Tags: jquery, html

i have table data . I need to display the table sum `Total` by summing of all the rows of `RowTotal column` inside that table. But in my loop its taking only the first row and excluding the second row .
Html Code:

```
<table class="view_job cust_view_job table-striped table text-center" style="width: 100%;border:1px solid #ccc">
    <thead>
        <tr style="background:#2b2e76" ;="">
            <th colspan="3" style="padding: 0;">
                <p style="color:white">
                   Bundle Two
                </p>
            </th>

            <th><p style="color:white" class="BundleB773423" id="B7734">Total : <span class="BundelRowTotalB7734">200</span></p></th>

        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th style="width:5%;text-align: center">Qty</th>
            <th style="width:5%;text-align: center">Days</th>
            <th style="width:10%;text-align: center">Rate</th>
            <th style="width:10%;text-align: center">Row Total</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>


            <td>
                <input type="text" value="1" readonly="" autocomplete="off" name="qty[]" placeholder="Qty" class="form-control Qty">
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" value="2" autocomplete="off" name="days[]" placeholder="Days" class="form-control Days">
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" value="100.00" autocomplete="off" id="rate_23" name="rate[]" placeholder="Rate" class="form-control rate">
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" value="200.00" autocomplete="off" readonly="" name="row_total[]" id="row_totalB773423" placeholder="Row Total" class="form-control rowTotal">
            </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>


                <td>
                    <input type="text" value="1" readonly="" autocomplete="off" name="qty[]" placeholder="Qty" class="form-control Qty">
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" value="1" autocomplete="off" name="days[]" placeholder="Days" class="form-control Days">
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" value="200.00" autocomplete="off" id="rate_24" name="rate[]" placeholder="Rate" class="form-control rate">
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" value="200.00" autocomplete="off" readonly="" name="row_total[]" id="row_totalB773424" placeholder="Row Total" class="form-control rowTotal">
                </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
```

Jquery code:

```
var calcObject = {
  run: function () {

    var id = ''; 
    var sum =bundleSum=qtyVal=daysVal=rateVal=rowtotal =calcVat=daysvalue=ratevalue=FinalRow=Bsum=0;

    $(".Qty").each(function () {
      //add only if the value is number
      if (!isNaN(this.value) && this.value.length != 0) {
        qtyVal =  parseFloat(this.value);
      }
        daysVal =  $(this).closest('tr').find("td:eq(1) input[type='text']").val();
        if (!isNaN(daysVal)) {
          daysvalue = parseFloat(daysVal);
        }
        rateVal =  $(this).closest('tr').find("td:eq(2) input[type='text']").val();
        if (!isNaN(rateVal)) {
          ratevalue = parseFloat(rateVal);
        }

        rowtotal = Math.round(parseFloat(qtyVal)*parseFloat(daysvalue)*parseFloat(ratevalue));
        if (!isNaN(rowtotal)) {
          FinalRow = parseFloat(rowtotal);
        }
        id =  $(this).closest('tr').find("td:eq(3) input[type='text']").attr('id');
        $('#'+id).val(parseFloat(FinalRow).toFixed(2));


    });
    var BundelID = '';
    $(".rowTotal").each(function () {
      //add only if the value is number
      if (!isNaN(this.value) && this.value.length != 0) {
        sum +=  parseFloat(this.value);
      }
      var RowID = $(this).attr('id');
      var suffix = RowID.match(/\d+/)[0];
      BundelID = $('.BundleB'+suffix).attr('id');

        if(RowID.indexOf(BundelID) != -1){
             var BValue = $('#'+RowID).val();
             if (!isNaN(BValue)) {
                Bsum +=  parseFloat(BValue);
              }
        }
        $('.BundelRowTotal'+BundelID).html(parseFloat(Bsum).toFixed(2));

    });

  }

};

$(function () {

  $(document).on('keyup', '.Days', function () {
    calcObject.run();
  });

  $(document).on('keyup', '.Qty', function () {
    calcObject.run();
  });
  $(document).on('keyup', '.rate', function () {
    calcObject.run();
  });


  $('.rowTotal').change(function () {

    calcObject.run();

  });

});
```

Fiddle demo here : [demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/fyhsz9ra/1304/)
I don't understand where i m doing wrong . any suggestions please.
Thank you .

Comment: Learn to debug your code: add `console.log(BundelID)` in the .rowTotal - for the second row, it's undefined

Comment: First one tries to find bundle matching `773423` 2nd `773424`  and the bundle row is `BundleB773423` so only the first matches

Comment: Yeah True ! Thank you i m checking that

Comment: @5367683, you also need to call the `run()` function to have correct results initially also, take a look at my answer

Answer (score 0):

> Your `bundleId` was coming wrong in second time & you have to call `run()` initially also

**Try this:-**

```js
var calcObject = {
  run: function () {

    var id = ''; 
    var sum =bundleSum=qtyVal=daysVal=rateVal=rowtotal =calcVat=daysvalue=ratevalue=FinalRow=Bsum=0;

    $(".Qty").each(function () {
      //add only if the value is number
      if (!isNaN(this.value) && this.value.length != 0) {
        qtyVal =  parseFloat(this.value);
      }
        daysVal =  $(this).closest('tr').find("td:eq(1) input[type='text']").val();
        if (!isNaN(daysVal)) {
          daysvalue = parseFloat(daysVal);
        }
        rateVal =  $(this).closest('tr').find("td:eq(2) input[type='text']").val();
        if (!isNaN(rateVal)) {
          ratevalue = parseFloat(rateVal);
        }

        rowtotal = Math.round(parseFloat(qtyVal)*parseFloat(daysvalue)*parseFloat(ratevalue));
        if (!isNaN(rowtotal)) {
          FinalRow = parseFloat(rowtotal);
        }
        id =  $(this).closest('tr').find("td:eq(3) input[type='text']").attr('id');
        $('#'+id).val(parseFloat(FinalRow).toFixed(2));

      
    });
    var BundelID = '';
    $(".rowTotal").each(function (index,value) {
      //add only if the value is number
      if (!isNaN(this.value) && this.value.length != 0) {
        sum +=  parseFloat(this.value);
      }
      var RowID = $(this).attr('id');
      var suffix = RowID.match(/\d+/)[0];
      if(index == 0){
      BundelID = $('.BundleB'+suffix).attr('id');
      }
      

        if(RowID.indexOf(BundelID) != -1){
             var BValue = $('#'+RowID).val();
             if (!isNaN(BValue)) {
                Bsum +=  parseFloat(BValue);
              }
        }
  $('.BundelRowTotal'+BundelID).html(parseFloat(sum).toFixed(2));
    });
   
 
  }

};

$(function () {
//run it first time also
calcObject.run();

  $(document).on('keyup', '.Days', function () {
    calcObject.run();
  });
  
  $(document).on('keyup', '.Qty', function () {
    calcObject.run();
  });
  $(document).on('keyup', '.rate', function () {
    calcObject.run();
  });


  $('.rowTotal').change(function () {

    calcObject.run();

  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="view_job cust_view_job table-striped table text-center" style="width: 100%;border:1px solid #ccc">
    <thead>
        <tr style="background:#2b2e76" ;="">
            <th colspan="3" style="padding: 0;">
                <p style="color:white">
                   Bundle Two
                </p>
            </th>
            
            <th><p style="color:white" class="BundleB773423" id="B7734">Total : <span class="BundelRowTotalB7734">200</span></p></th>
           
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th style="width:5%;text-align: center">Qty</th>
            <th style="width:5%;text-align: center">Days</th>
            <th style="width:10%;text-align: center">Rate</th>
            <th style="width:10%;text-align: center">Row Total</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            
            
            <td>
                <input type="text" value="1" readonly="" autocomplete="off" name="qty[]" placeholder="Qty" class="form-control Qty">
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" value="2" autocomplete="off" name="days[]" placeholder="Days" class="form-control Days">
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" value="100.00" autocomplete="off" id="rate_23" name="rate[]" placeholder="Rate" class="form-control rate">
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" value="200.00" autocomplete="off" readonly="" name="row_total[]" id="row_totalB773423" placeholder="Row Total" class="form-control rowTotal">
            </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                
              
                <td>
                    <input type="text" value="1" readonly="" autocomplete="off" name="qty[]" placeholder="Qty" class="form-control Qty">
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" value="1" autocomplete="off" name="days[]" placeholder="Days" class="form-control Days">
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" value="200.00" autocomplete="off" id="rate_24" name="rate[]" placeholder="Rate" class="form-control rate">
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" value="200.00" autocomplete="off" readonly="" name="row_total[]" id="row_totalB773424" placeholder="Row Total" class="form-control rowTotal">
                </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
```

Comment: Don't beg for reputation, it diminishes you.